# Xpath pass a variable in a predicate

Tags: python, variables, selenium, xpath, predicate

I need help passing a variable in a predicate via Xpath using Python for a web scrape.

Xpath Predicate path example:

```
//*[@id="rev_exp_div_1370887"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td
```

Not Working Predicate Variable

```
by_xpath('//*[@id="rev_exp_div_1370887"]/table["' + str(x) + '"]/tbody/tr[1]/td').text
```

The code passes syntax checks and runs successfully, but doesn't hit the correct table (any at all, in fact) even though x is returning the correct value when I double check it with a print x.  It works, of course, if I hard code the value in (shown in the top line of code) so I know the path is correct at least.

Idea, comments or suggestions welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Your `/table["' + str(x) + '"]` does not need the ". Try `/table[' + str(x) + ']`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  the problem has been solved.  So simple, I feel foolish. You made my day. Cheers.

Comment: @MarkRowlands Would you mind adding this as an answer? Then, it can be accepted and the matter is settled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `/table["' + str(x) + '"]` does not need the ".

Try `/table[' + str(x) + ']` instead.